# Descargar archivos usando rest api laravel en Postman

Tags: php, laravel, rest

estoy diseñando un pequeño servicio de exportación de archivos en laravel usando phpoffice y dompdf. Mi implementación genera los archivos, pero cuando lo pruebo en postman para ver como funciona el mecanismo de descarga me sale esto:

[image: Exportar archivos en postman]

En vez de ocurrir un evento de descarga como si estuviera navegando solo me sale la vista previa del archivo. No entiendo por que?

Mi código:

```
public function excel(Request $request){

        $validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'title'=>'required',
            'items'=>'required'

        ]);
            if($validator->fails()){
                 return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()],404);
            }

         $data=$this->getControl($request->items);
         $keys=$data['keys'];
         $values=$data['values'];

       /*  $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
         $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
         $greenNotBold = array("font" => array("bold" => true,"size"=>12,),);*/
               //crear lector de office 
         $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Xlsx'); 
         $reader->setReadDataOnly(FALSE);
         $spreadsheet = $reader->load("../storage/test.xlsx");
         $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
         $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();  //obtiene la hoja de calculo

          $theme=$this->find('$Subject',$worksheet);
          $titleCoordinate=$this->find('$column',$worksheet);
          $valueCoordinate=$this->find('$values',$worksheet);


           if($theme){
             $greenNotBold = array("font" => array("bold" => true,"size" => 20,),);
             $column=$worksheet->getCell($theme)->getColumn();
             $worksheet->getColumnDimension($column)
             ->setAutoSize(false);
             //$worksheet->mergeCells($theme:$theme[0])->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 
             $worksheet->getStyle($theme)
                                  ->applyFromArray($greenNotBold);


             $worksheet->setCellValue($theme,$request->title); 

           }



        if($titleCoordinate!==null && $valueCoordinate!==null ){
            $column=$worksheet->getCell($titleCoordinate)->getColumn();
            $valuecol=$worksheet->getCell($valueCoordinate)->getColumn();
           ///  return response('sdf',200);
            $greenNotBold = array("font" => array("bold" => true,"size" => 12,),);
           $worksheet->fromArray($keys,NULL,$titleCoordinate);
           $worksheet->getStyle($titleCoordinate.':'.chr(ord($titleCoordinate)+sizeof($keys)).$worksheet->getCell($titleCoordinate)->getRow())
                          ->applyFromArray($greenNotBold);

          $worksheet->fromArray($values,NULL,$valueCoordinate);
          $writer=new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
          $writer->save('../storage/'.$request->title.'.xlsx');

        }



         return response()->download('../storage/'.$request->title.'.xlsx','nameoffile.pdf')->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
    }
```

Comment: Al consumir tu servicio desde un aplicativo, necesitas guardar esos bytes como un fichero, al consumirlos con un navegador, el naveador sabe como interpretar esos bytes, por eso puede mostrar una vista previa como un pdf o descargarlos como un csv, xls

Comment: copie esos bytes y los guarde como archivo xlsx y nada me sale corrupto.

Comment: como llamas  a tú servicio, desde jquery, aplicativo de escritorio ?

Comment: No no uso jquery, uso una rest api para eso.

Comment: si, pero desde donde pretendes hacer ese llamado, desde una página web o desde una aplicación de escritorio,

Comment: es una aplicacion de escritorio. Postman es una herramienta extensiva de google chrome, sin embargo, es puesto como aplicacion desktop.

Comment: Creo que no me estoy explicando adecuadamente, ese llamado a la api, necesitas hacerlo directamente tu o lo vas a utilizar para implementarlo en una aplicación, osea que con postman estás realizando pruebas, la cosa es que el archivo que estas descargando con postman salen todos los bytes del archivo, el navegador sabe como interpretarlos, postman no, no puedes copiar y pegarlo en un archivo y cambiarle la extensión. Lo que se hace es obtener esos datos en base64, y cuando los vayas a guardar los decodificas de base 64 y guardas los bytes como el fichero que necesitas (pdf o xls).

Comment: es para un aplicacion web

Comment: pretendes imprimirlo hacia el mismo navegador?

Comment: Sii eso mismo. Eso es lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 1):

Por si alguien mas se encuentra con el problema de probar un metodo api que descargue un archivo, en postman tiene la opción de "Send and Download", segun el sitio oficial de postman "Para los tipos de respuesta binaria, debe seleccionar Enviar y descargar, lo que le permitirá guardar la respuesta en su disco duro. Luego puede verlo usando el visor apropiado"

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/responses

[image: Opcion Send and Download de Postman]